# Initialize log4Net as early as possible with NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, log4net, nunit-2.5

I'm wondering what is the best way to initialize log4Net in a NUnit project. Of course I want to call the init code (ie. `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`) as soon as I can to get as many early log output as I can. But since my project is run through NUnit, I have little control on its entry point.

According to NUnit documentation, it should call some constructors first, then a method marked with the `[SetUp]` attribute in a class marked with `[TestFixtureSetup]`.

So, First, I created a static helper class which I can call several times without trouble.

```
  public static class LoggingFacility
  {
    private static bool _loggerIsUp = false;

    public static void InitLogger()
    {
      if (_loggerIsUp == false)
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(f);

      _loggerIsUp = true;
    }
  }
```

Then, I made all my `[TestFixtureSetup]` inherit a single one that does pretty much nothing else than calling `LoggingFacility.initLogger()`. But that still leaves all constructors that are run earlier, in an order I can only assume random. And moreover, it will probably do some static initializations before I am even able to execute some code.

In fact, as I can see in my log, the first 4 seconds or so of execution are completely unrecorded.

Does it mean I will have to call my `InitLogger()` in every constructor and forbid the use of any static initializer? That's tough job!

Does somebody know a magic trick with this?

Comment: Just wondering for which purposes you are using log4net in tests, to log test progress/results or to instantiate a logger as dependency of some classes?

Comment: @sll: I use two logging outputs: first one is for test outputs to be a little more verbose than NUnit itself, and the second one (the one I need to be ready fast) is for debugging the test app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work mate provided me with the following workaround, that does the job:

In all my classes that require logging, I had the following logger initialization

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

I simply changed it to a singleton initializer

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LoggingFacility.GetLoggerWithInit(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

/*** ... ***/

public static class LoggingFacility
{
  private static bool _loggerIsUp = false;

  public static ILog GetLoggerWithInit(Type declaringType)
  {
    if (_loggerIsUp == false)
      XmlConfigurator.Configure(_log4NetCfgFile);
    _loggerIsUp = true;
    return LogManager.GetLogger(declaringType);
  }
}
```

Because I have this code in every class, this static initializer has to be called very early by NUnit wile instantiating my test classes.

Next step is to make that thread safe :(

Answer (score 4):

For single initialization point you should use class marked with [`[SetUpFixture]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4) attribute and method marked with `[SetUp]`, for example:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestsInitializer
{
    [SetUp]
    public void InitializeLogger()
    {
        LoggingFacility.InitLogger();
    }
}
```

Now, this method (`[SetUp] InitializeLogger`) will run *before any test* is run, same as one marked with `[TearDown]` will run once all tests are run. But here's the catch - what does ***any*** and ***all*** mean in this context? Tests from classes **declared in the same namespace as class marked with `[SetUpFixture]`**.

For example, assuming hierarchy like this:

```
- Tests
--- Business
----- TestsInitializer.cs // SetUpFixture class
----- FirstBusinessTests.cs
----- SecondBusinesTests.cs
--- ComplexLogic
----- VeryComplexLogicTests.cs
```

`First` and `SecondBusinessTests` will run **after** `SetUp` from `TestsInitializer`, however `VeryComplexLogicTests` might run in random order.

According to [linked documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4), if you declare `SetUpFixture` class outside of any namespace, setup and teardown will apply for entire assembly:

> Only one SetUpFixture should be created in a given namespace. A SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly.

Comment: thanks for the namespace tips, that is much appreciated. Still, my problem is that NUnit runs lots of code *before* even wondering about [SetUpFixture]: contructors and static initializers, and I'd like to log this code too

Comment: @PPC: what kind of code is run *before*? You mean NUnit's initialization or your code, like test classes constructors and such? I'm pretty sure `SetUpFixture` is as soon as it gets in terms of hooking up your custom code to NUnit. *Maybe* you can work your ways with config file, but to be honest I have never seen anybody doing such stuff before.

Comment: Yes, I mean constructors and such. My first logging entry starts at about 5 seconds uptime and I don't see most of my constructors logging in there.